# Nginx server location configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I want the domains example.com/a/1234/asdf, example.com/a/7890/qwer ,..., example.com/a/* to serve a webpage from the same index file, /var/www/foo/bar/index.php

My nginx is configed like this:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php;

        rewrite */a/(.*) /var/www/foo/bar/index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

When I goto example.com/a/1234/asdf I get a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have a file `/var/www/var/www/foo/bar/index.php`. So of course it can't be found. Remember that these paths are relative to the document `root`.

You probably want something like:

```
rewrite */a/(.*) /foo/bar/index.php last;
```

Comment: OK I tried that fix and I'm still getting the error msg.  Is there any way to debug this?

Comment: You can turn on the `rewrite_log`.

Comment: I see this error in error.log open() "example.com/a/1234/asdf" failed (2: No such file or directory)...so its not trying the rewrite at all.  And I have restarted nginx.

Comment: My current config: 
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php;
        rewrite \*/a/(.\*) /foo/bar/index.php last;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}

Comment: I might have found the problem.  '$sudo service nginx restart' is not actually restarting nginx.